# Jquery image count elements

Tags: jquery, image, count

I'm working with bjqs slider and fancybox. I'm trying to calculate the number of images shown and display them as Image 1/3, 2/3, 3/3 etc... 
At the moment, the script is showing count, but its not responding to first click and count number of total images is wrong.

Any help would be appreciated, Here is the code:

```
<script>
$(function() { $('.toggle').click(function() { $('.col_2').toggle(); return false; }); });

$(window).resize(function(){ if(window.innerWidth > 960) { $(".col_2").removeAttr("style"); } });
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('#banner-slide').bjqs({
    animtype      : 'slide',
    height        : 690,
    width         : 536,
    responsive    : true,
    randomstart   : false,
  });
  $(".fancybox").fancybox();

    //var numImgs = $('#banner-slide img').length - 2;
    //  $('.count').text(numImgs);


    var images = $('#banner-slide img');
    var imageIndex = 1;

            $("li.bjqs-next a").click(function(){

                $('.count').text(imageIndex++ + "/" + images.length/2);
                if( imageIndex > images.length/2 )
                {
                    imageIndex = 1;   
                }
                else {  }
            })

            $("li.bjqs-prev a").click(function(){
                $('.count').text(imageIndex-- + "/" + images.length/2);
                if( imageIndex < 1 )
                {
                    imageIndex = images.length/2;   
                }
            })


            // $('ul.bjqs-controls li.bjqs-next a').click( function(){ $('.count').text(($current++) + "/" + $iCount); });
            //$('ul.bjqs-controls li.bjqs-prev a').click( function(){ $('.count').text(($current--) + "/" + iCount); });


    $('.count').text("1" + "/" + images.length/2);
    //setInterval(function () {  }, 1000);

});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your image index is incremented after you update the value. Try replacing imageIndex++ with ++imageIndex

Comment: Thx for the help. I tried replacing imageIndex++ with ++imageIndex but its not working.

Comment: Are you sure? Try saving the string as a variable and console.log it because that imageIndex++ part is going to pass 1 in when you click the first time which will mean you have 1 displaying under the second image. The same thing is happening for your imageIndex-- part so change that to --imageIndex. That has to be a bug even if it isn't the main one.

Comment: After changing to --imageIndex > it is working! Slides count is appending normally, but when it reaches the final count for example 5/5 - by clikcing NEXT it doesnt start from 1/5. Any hints on that?

Comment: Your problem there is that you reset the imageIndex after you set the text. Try resetting the text of the .count field inside your if statement.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I will reset the .count field.